# Swift Functional Programming: iterating tuples

Tags: swift, swift2

This is the loop I have using `for`:

```
var titles = [String]()
var urls   = [String]()

for (name, details) : (String, JSON) in json["codes"] {
    titles.append(details["title"].string!)
    urls.append(details["url"].string!)
}
```

and it works, but **is there a way I could make it more "functional" using, say, `flatMap` or something?**

Comment: What `// Do something ...` should do? I mean what's your goal.

Comment: I get values of `details` and append them to respective arrays. However, if I just want to log something or assign some stuff I read along the way, won't I get an "unused" warning (if I don't need the result of the map)? How would I eliminate that?

Comment: @robertvojta I updated my question :)

Comment: The functional version of a `for` construct is the `forEach` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
let titles = json["codes"].map { $0.1["title"].string! }
let urls = json["codes"].map { $0.1["url"].string! }
```